# Run docker container with open62541 server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: image, docker, raspberry-pi, containers, open62541

### Description

I am connected to my raspberry pi 1 ( via putty and I have already followed the steps as described [here](https://open62541.org/doc/current/building.html) at "Building Debian Packages inside Docker Container with CMake on Ubuntu or Debian"

I have cloned the docker-deb-builder repo and build both the dockerfile-ubuntu-18.04 and
dockerfile-ubuntu-17.04.
Then, I have cloned the open62541 repo and checked out pack/1.0.
Afterwards, I have created the output folder in the docker-deb-builder folder and tried to run the 
following command in the development folder:
`./build -i docker-deb-builder:18.04 -o output ~/ma/development/open62541`

But it fails with following error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ma/dockerVersion/docker-deb-builder $ sudo ./build -i docker-deb-builder:18.04 -o output ~/ma/dockerVersion/open62541
Running docker:
docker run -it -it -v /home/pi/ma/development/open62541:/source-ro:ro -v /home/pi/ma/development/docker-deb-builder/output:/output -v /home/pi/ma/development/docker-deb-builder/build-helper.sh:/build-helper.sh:ro -e USER=0 -e GROUP=0 --rm  docker-deb-builder:18.04 /build-helper.sh
Unable to find image 'docker-deb-builder:18.04' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker-deb-builder, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to run a docker container (with an open62541 server running in it) on my raspberry pi. 
Questions:
- How can I solve the problem described above?
- How or where can I integrate my customized open62541 server code?

### Background Information / Reproduction Steps

Running the command cat /etc/os-release gives me the following information:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ma/dockerVersion/docker-deb-builder $ cat /etc/os-release                                PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: as descriped in the docs , you need to build the image docker build -t docker-deb-builder:18.04 -f Dockerfile-ubuntu-18.04 .

Comment: that doesn't work. please have a look to my other post on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60562596/building-the-dockerfile-executes-with-non-zero-code-139

Answer (score 0):

## Issue 1 - running a container by tag (but not finding it by tag)

Firstly, the error `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker-deb-builder` occurs when you `docker run` using a image name that cannot be found locally, so it goes off and tries to find `docker-deb-builder` on hub.docker.com (publicly) and if you go look there are none with that *exact* name.

The error is basically telling you;

- I couldn't find `docker-deb-builder` locally
- I couldn't find `docker-deb-builder` on hub.docker.com (public)
- I want to try hub.docker.com (private) but you are not logged in

So you might first try to build the container and `docker tag` it with `docker-deb-builder` so you can then find it locally with the command you provided in this issue.

## Issue 2 - building on armv7 (raspberry pi)

The page you linked to has instructions for;
`git clone https://github.com/tsaarni/docker-deb-builder.git`

Looking at `tsaarni/docker-deb-builder` on github for the 18.04 image you're targetting i found [the Docekrfile](https://github.com/tsaarni/docker-deb-builder/blob/master/Dockerfile-ubuntu-18.04) and it is using `ubuntu:18.04` and you will need to modify this to use `ubuntu:18.04@sha256:60a99a670b980963e4a9d882f631cba5d26ba5d14ccba2aa82a4e1f4d084fb1f` which is the signature for the armv7.

Might just add, to make sure in case you're not aware, to run on armv7 you must also **`docker build`** it on armv7